# CMB 2 'add new button'

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible after adding a meta box using CMB2 to add a button for a user on the back end to click on and it will generate the same metabox kind of like an add new button and the user can add as many meta boxes of the same type as he/she wants. is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is done with the field type "group". While this doesnt technically make the entire metabox repeatable, it can still achieve the result you're looking for if you place all of the fields you want inside of the group.

Basically, you add the field group, then use the `add_group_field()` function for each field you want in the group. You still set up your metabox like normal, and add the group field and then any other fields you want in it.

as an example I set up a metabox with `$cmb_infobox` as the variable. My group field looks like this:

```
<?php
$group_field_id = $cmb_infobox->add_field( array(
    'id'          => $prefix . 'group',
    'type'        => 'group',
    'description' => __( 'Generates reusable form entries', 'cmb2' ),
    'options'     => array(
        'group_title'   => __( 'Info Box {#}', 'cmb2' ), // since version 1.1.4, {#} gets replaced by row number
        'add_button'    => __( 'Add Info Box', 'cmb2' ),
        'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Info Box', 'cmb2' ),
        'sortable'      => true, // beta
        // 'closed'     => true, // true to have the groups closed by default
    ),
) );
```

You can add any field you want to this group, but it will just look a little different to get things started, and you only need IDs that are unique within the group. For example i can have a WYSIWYG field with the ID of 'content' in the group with no conflicts with the WordPress editor or anything else with that ID in another group field. As you can see there are also array values for the "add" button text and the "remove" button text.

Here's a simple text field within my repeatable infobox group:

```
<?php
$cmb_infobox->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
    'name' => 'Title',
    'id'   => 'title',
    'type' => 'text',
    // 'repeatable' => true, // Repeatable fields are supported w/in repeatable groups (for most types)
) );
```

The important differences are the first line and the ID. The rest of the values are the same as normal. Make sure you have the starting variable correct.

To bring this to the frontend, you end up using a `foreach` loop.

here's a cut down version of my infobox going to the front end.

```
<?php
foreach ( (array) $entries as $key => $entry ) {

    // Store field values in variables to use in markup
    if ( isset( $entry['icon'] ) ) {

        $icon = esc_html( $entry['icon'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $entry['title'] ) ) {

        $title = esc_html( $entry['title'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $entry['content'] ) ) {

        $content = esc_html( $entry['content'] );
    }

    echo $icon;
    echo $title;
    echo $content;
}
```

This is basically how the documentation will tell you to do it as well, however I always use brackets with conditionals.

You can find out more about it in the CMB2 field types documentation. https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#file

Click on `group` in the field type list and it'll take you right to the section that goes over it.